# Send values get from append forms to spring controller

Tags: spring, model-view-controller

I was creating a model where the structure as follows:

```
public class A {

private Long id;

private Type type;

private Set<String> names;

private Set<Long> ids;

private Set<String> subnames;

private Set<Long> subids;
...........

}
```

I would like to create the model, with multiple fields as many as I like.
so the I have created the form as follows to add new rows dynamically.

```
Creation Form: One of the fields-->
<form>
<div id="addNewname" class="form-group">
                                <label>name</label>
                                <div class="col-lg-4">
                                    <input type="text" name="name_1" id="name"  readonly>
                                </div>
                                <button id="btnAddname" type="button"
                                type="hidden"
                                    value="btnAddName" name="btnAddName">Add
                                    New</button>
                            </div></form>
```

With the Script to add new as follows:

int count = 1;

```
    $(document).on("click", "#btnAddNew", function(){
            count++;
    $('#addNewNew').after(
             '<div>' +
             '<label> New Name</label>'+
             '<div >' +
                    '<select name="name_'+ count +'">'+
                        '<option value="0">None</option>' +
                        '<c:forEach items="${names}" var="name">' +
                            '<option value="${name.id}">${name.name}</option> '+
                        '</c:forEach>'+
                    '</select>'+
                '</div>'+
            '</div>');
         });
```

I was able to send the value to the controller of the value name="name_1" where the form been defined, but I could not do the same for the values created from the append form--script.

Any idea or suggestion to work out this, I have tried many methods but ...

Answer (score 0):

You may use LazyList to add as many names you want.

In your command class, instead of using Set to define your names, try this,

```
import org.apache.commons.collections.FactoryUtils;
import org.apache.commons.collections.list.LazyList;
```

...
    private List names = LazyList.decorate( new ArrayList(), 
        FactoryUtils.instantiateFactory(String.class));
...

In the Jsp page, all that are needed is using the arrayIndex to access or bind values. i.e. 
    <form:input path="names[0]" cssErrorClass="errorInput" maxlength="30"/>

In the javascript, do the same, use the arrayIndex when your create more text input on the fly.